# Android SIP Chat Messaging

Tags: android, chat, sip, messaging

I have to implement chat messaging using Android SIP client but unable to find any related classes or listener. I have already implemented calling feature using SIP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use pjsip or Linphone opensource project.Both libraries  are written using c code and well documented to build for android with sample application.

If you want pure java implementation of sip IM ,go for jainsip stack based implementation.Actually android default sip client is based on jainsip but it not support Im and only works in wifi.

Telestax implementation of jainsip helps to create apps for android.You can read this [documentation](https://telestax.com/jain-sip-stack-for-android/)  for more details.Also a sample android implementation you can find [here.](https://github.com/arslan70/JAIN-SIP-Android)

Comment: I am using linphone but didn't find much documentation, can you please help me to get create Simple manager using linphone to create voice call and chat.

Comment: sample code are available at linphone tutorial .check this link https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android/tree/master/src/android/org/linphone/tutorials

Answer (score 1):

It seems like SIP IM is not implemented in the Android SIP client.

However you should be able to easily implement this yourself.

All you need to check is [RFC 3428](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3428.txt).
Just check the example (search for "MESSAGE sip") and it should be obvious from here.

Another solution would be to use some other open-source SIP stack with SIP MESSAGE support.

Answer (score 1):

To implement both **call** and **messaging** facility in Android app, you can implement through PJSIP.It has several set of libraries to implement new features.
It has all VOIP functionalities to implement in android app.

The documentation to implement PJSIP in Android,
https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android

The above link specifies, how to implement PJSIP in android platform.

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't have support as of now..Can you check
Check this https://telestax.com/jain-sip-stack-for-android/

WHY DO THIS?
Limitations of native sip stack.
The stock native android sip stack is built on top of JAIN SIP but it does not have all functionality, there is no support for IM, presence and video calls right now. Google forked SIP Stack and never really updated the SIP API that is shipped by default and used the same package names as the original JAIN SIP project. This proved to be a major hassle to developers that wanted to add SIP capabilities worldwide as they couldn’t use JAIN SIP out of the box.

JAIN SIP is Java based 
An opensource implementation of the stack can be found here. It is a java based SIP stack which allows you to integrate the sip stack seamlessly in your android application without the hassle of NDK.

A Complete SIP Stack
JAIN SIP is a full implementation of the RFC 3261 Specification and as well as support for several SIP RFCs.